# (XCODE IPHONE)Changing language through change.php?lang=en after loading a webpage

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview

Hi guys I'm trying to load an html page, and after the loading I want to be executed `change.php?lang=eng`.
I have this now when the program starts:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Treviturismo.it";
    link = @"http://www.treviturismo.it/dev/index.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Maybe I can do an IF to check if the page has been loaded, then:

```
link = @"http://www.treviturismo.it/dev/change.php?lang=en";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Is this a good way?? I don't know what to type in the `if()`, to check if the first page has been loaded!
Can anyone help me?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen for the page loading event using the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // init code...

   myWebView.delegate = self; // your class must implement the UIWebViewDelegate protocol

   link = @"http://www.treviturismo.it/dev/index.php";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
   NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   // if you want this method to not being called again, do this :
   webView.delegate = nil;

   // then do your request to change.php here
   link = @"http://www.treviturismo.it/dev/change.php?lang=en";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
   requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: Thanks now I understand, it works!! But after executing the code in the method webViewDidFinishLoad, the page in the WebView starts refreshing itself for ever

Comment: Yes because the webViewDidFinishLoad is called after all requests, so it's is called after the change.php request too. I've updated the sample code to deal with this problem.